# Professeure v. professeur pour les femmes qui enseignent?

Tags: choix-de-mot, professions, genre-biologique

Mon professeur de français a dit que l'on utilisait « professeur » pour toutes les personnes qui enseignent, que ce soient des hommes ou des femmes. Cependant, alors que je lisais des sites sur Internet, j'ai vu « une professeure » utilisé à propos d'une enseignante.

Est-ce que seul l'un des deux mots est correct, ou est-ce qu'une « professeure » est un néologisme créé par les féministes face au nom traditionnel ?

Comment: See [feminisation des noms de professions](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9minisation_des_noms_de_m%C3%A9tiers_en_fran%C3%A7ais)

Comment: Please note: when speaking the e on the end of professeure is not "heard".

Answer (score 6):

## En francais

Tu soulèves là une question difficile. Traditionnellement, on dit "Madame le professeur", tout comme on dit "Madame le Président". Mais avec la montée des mouvements tels que le féminisme, certaines personnes ont considéré que cette tradition était machiste. En conséquence, il a été décidé que ces noms de professions pouvait désormais être féminisés.

Les deux orthographes sont donc correctes, le plus dur étant de ne pas froisser les gens en utilisant l'une ou l'autre. A noter que dans certains cadres cependant, il faut utiliser la forme "conjuguée", comme on le voit dans [cet article](http://www.lefigaro.fr/politique/2014/10/07/01002-20141007ARTFIG00324-madame-la-presidente-ou-le-president-quelle-est-la-regle.php):

> Le débat sur la féminisation des fonctions politiques a rebondi lundi après la sanction d'un député UMP pour avoir appelé la présidente de séance «Madame le président» [...] Trois mots qui ont fait bondir l'intéressée. Celle-ci n'a pas tardé à rappeler le parlementaire à l'ordre pour ne pas avoir féminisé sa fonction, avec inscription au procès-verbal. Résultat: l'élu va être privé d'un quart de son indemnité parlementaire pendant un mois, soit 1378 euros. En prononçant cette sentence, Sandrine Mazetier n'a rien fait d'autre que s'appuyer sur le règlement de l'Assemblée nationale. Une instruction du bureau du Palais Bourbon, prise en 1998 et rappelée en 2000, fait obligation de féminiser les fonctions exercées par des femmes dans l'Assemblée. Dans l'enceinte de l'hémicycle, on doit donc dire «Madame la députée» ou «Madame la présidente» (de commission, de séance, etc). Cette règle ne s'applique pas en revanche aux fonctions ministérielles.

---

## In English

This is a sensitive subject: Traditionally, you use the masculine word for everyone, but with the rise of feminist-related interpretations, it has been deemed by some as "machismo". So now, both spellings are accepted as correct, the hardest part is not to hurt the beliefs of the people you're talking/writing to. As for myself, I often have to ask the people I talk to how they would like to be addressed.

Please note, though, that in some places (like the National Assembly), the feminine version of the title is the required usage.

The newspaper article summary: A French politician used "Madame **le** président" in the National Assembly while referring to the National Assembly's sitting president, and was reprimanded by a 25% reduction in his salary."

Comment: _le plus dur étant de ne pas froisser les gens en utilisant l'une ou l'autre._ ? Quelqu'un a été froissé un jour à ce propos ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington Je ne sais pas si vous êtes de France ou pas, mais en France, le débat a fait rage. Encore aujourd'hui, certaines personnes s’offusquent lorsque j'emploie la version masculine de "Président". Lorsqu'on passe sur des plateaux télévisés publics, il s'agit d'un des sujets auxquels il faut faire attention

Comment: Je pense que c'est exagéré. Le racisme est punissable, pas le "faux pas" qui consiste à dire Madame Le Président ..

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington J'ai retiré la comparaison de mon commentaire, qui était très exagéré. J'ai modifié ma réponse en ajoutant un lien vers un article ou une condamnation a eu lieu pour utilisation de la forme masculine, mais cela est un cas très précis, je dois l'admettre. Mais il m'est déjà arrivé dans un cadre professionnel d'avoir quelqu'un qui réponde à un de mes mail en me précisant qu'elle n'appréciait pas que j'utilise la forme masculine de son titre.

Comment: Why bother with English that is full of  mistakes?

Comment: @Nathan Right. Thank you for explaining that. :) No, I wasn't "being mean". I simply did not understand the reason for it. Now, I do.

Comment: According to l'Académie française "Madame la Présidente" designate the President wife. In Justice, usage is to say "Madame le Président". The parliament has chosen its own rules.

Comment: @LaurentPELE De nos jours "Madame la présidente" désignerait une femme présidente. On parlera plutôt de "la Première Dame" pour parler de la femme du président.

Comment: Pas forcément, l'académie française a récemment rappelé sa règle concernant l'usage de Madame la Présidente. Voir aussi http://www.academie-francaise.fr/le-dictionnaire-la-9e-edition/exemples-de-remarques-normatives "Madame la Ministre, qui est apparu en 1997, constitue une faute d’accord résultant de la confusion de la personne et de la fonction"

Comment: Le [topo](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4015) de la BDL (Québec) pour fins de comparaison et autres infos. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

both terms "professeur" (traditional) or "professeure" (neologism) can be used to designate a female teacher. But the problem is that the right term to use depends of what prefers this person and there is no way to know it before she uses it !